# Can't boot into Linux partition after installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mac, macbook, multi-boot

I just installed Ubuntu. I created a partition in MacOSx using Disk utility, then deleted the partition and installed Ubuntu on the free space created.
After the installation, Ubuntu said it would reboot. I hang on shutdown (which is normal, as google told me), so I used the power button to turn the MacBook off.

Now I want to boot into Ubuntu. Pressing option/alt on startup only shows me the MacOSx and Windows partition.

Also, the Linux partition isn't showing up on my MacOSx desktop. And in Disk Utility, I can see 3 grayed out partitions: "disk0s4", "disk0s5" and "Linux Swap".

What can I do to boot into Ubuntu without losing my other partitions?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The process of dual booting Mac OS X and linux is messy and not that easy unless you have a good grasp of linux (and not be afraid to use the terminal).

The bootloader in Macs only supports booting into Mac OS X or Windows (with bootcamp). To boot into linux, you have to install a custom bootloader, like rEFIt.

There is already a thread detailing this process at Ubuntu Forums: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=198453